# How to get the exact size of a file in windows?

Tags: windows

The size info in default windows explorer is not accurate, for example, a `.txt` with a single character is `1 KB`.

How can I get the exact file size in `Byte`(not the default `KB`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you right click on the file, select `Properties` and look at the `Size` (not `Size on Disk`), it will show you the exact size as `1 Byte`.

Comment: I see it now,but where's the file name restored?

Comment: @win The *name* of the file, along with most other meta-data, is kept in the Master File Table.

Comment: You can also use MS-DOS command to view the exact sizes. Open command line window (`Start` > `Run` and type `cmd.exe` and hit Enter), navigate to the folder your file resides in and type `dir`. You will see `1` next to your text file which is displayed in `Bytes`.

Comment: Where's the Master File Table located?

Comment: @win the MFT is not easily accessible - it's the very core internal basics of the file system, it keeps track of what files are where (both in your directory tree and in physical location on the disk) and most information about then.

Comment: @win - The file name is not a property of the file. It's a property of the filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

Open the folder in [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/). That way you can see the exact size of all the files in a folder without having to click on each one.

Comment: PeaZip is the same. Great suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Hit `Alt + Enter` to show Properties (or right-click). Look at values of `Size:` and `Size on disk:`

Also Details tab of Properties provides this info.

Comment: It seems file name is not included in `Size`,then where is it restored?

Comment: All file metadata (some of which you can see in file properties) including file name are handled by your filesystem (NTFS, FAT32).